# IF inside UNTIL. Not working any suggestions!

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
selected=MU
team=xyz
until [ $selected = $team ]
do
    echo "Guess the best team:
    Manchester United->MU
    Arsenal      ->AR
    Chelsea      ->CH"
    read team
    if [ $selected -ne $team ]
        then
        echo "You are wrong!!! Try again"
    fi
done
echo "Correct!! Manchester united is the best"
```

Comment: At least, tell us what happens when you *try* to run this code.

Comment: guess: line 20: [: CH: integer expression expected error shows up

Comment: Your code doesn't have 20 lines. Which is the line that doesn't work?

Comment: the IF section is messing up with the program without it everything works fine but without the error message obviously.

Comment: Oops this is just a section of overall program so the line 20 meaning the line with IF command my mistake!!!

Comment: one more thing what can be done to avoid the first echo message from being displayed if wrong option is choosen!!!

Comment: You have to put it outside until loop, under team=xyz  (please confirm the correct answer :) )

Comment: thanks everyone!!! I got the expected result :DDD Cheers!!!!

Comment: Use the `help` command at a bash prompt to learn about bash commands: `help test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it, first I got:

```
line 12: [: MU: integer expression expected
```

since it was trying to compare strings but expected integers. Using `==` and `!=` works for strings, or as below too.

Quoting variables is a good idea in case someone types in a space, you'll get a different error:

```
line 4: [: too many arguments
```

So basically, you need

```
until [ "$selected" == "$team" ]
...
   if [ ! "$selected" == "$team" ]
```

Comment: line 20 was my mistake as this was just a section of a program I was working on and thanks for suggesting the better approach :D

Comment: Welcome :-) Upvotes &/or selecting a correct answer are good for thanks on these sites 8-]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: There's an error in line 10. The operator -ne is for integers, != is for strings.

Long answer follows.

Look again at the error message.

```
test.sh: line 10: [: MU: integer expression expected
```

That left square bracket is actually a command that lives on your filesystem, not a syntactic element as many would expect. As most commands in *nix, it has a man page you can check with:

```
man [
```

where you'll find the list of all the tests it is able to do for you:

```
...
STRING1 != STRING2
  the strings are not equal
...
INTEGER1 -ne INTEGER2
  INTEGER1 is not equal to INTEGER2
...
```

Note that *[* and *test* are the same command and you're probably going to see both of them throughout your carreer.

Shell scripting can be very hard at first, but don't get discouraged because it's worth it.

I find that bash's option -x is very useful when debugging shell scripts. When used, bash echoes all commands before actually running them.

```
$ bash -x test.sh
+ selected=MU
+ team=xyz
+ '[' MU = xyz ']'
+ echo 'Guess the best team:
    Manchester United->MU
    Arsenal      ->AR
    Chelsea      ->CH' Guess the best team:
    Manchester United->MU
    Arsenal      ->AR
    Chelsea      ->CH
+ read team MU
+ '[' MU -ne MU ']' test.sh: line 10: [: MU: integer expression expected
+ '[' MU = MU ']'
+ echo 'Correct!! Manchester united is the best' Correct!! Manchester united is the best
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if [ $selected -ne $team ]
```

with

```
if [ $selected != $team ]
```

The `-ne` operator can only compare numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in the comparison of strings:

Error: `if [ $selected -ne $team ]` this is integer comparison, for the strings: `if [ $selected != $team ]`